# QTableView - change selection when scrolling

Tags: qt4

I have a QTableView. I want the selection to be moved when i scroll - so the cursor would be always visible.

[image]

There is `QTableView.selectRow(rowNo)`, but do you have a suggestion where to call this?

Ideally i would like upon scrolling the selected row to be in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this (PyQt4):

Upon init i connect to scrollbar event:

```
    self.tableView.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.onScroll)
```

Then in the handler:

```
def onScroll(self, *args):
    "Ensure that selected row moves when scrolling - it must be always visible."
    tableView = self.tableView
    currentRow = tableView.selectionModel().currentIndex().row()
    rect = tableView.viewport().rect()
    topRow = tableView.indexAt(rect.topLeft()).row()
    if currentRow < topRow:
        tableView.selectRow(topRow)
    else:
        bottomRow = tableView.indexAt(rect.bottomLeft()).row()
        if currentRow > bottomRow:
            tableView.selectRow(bottomRow)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use  method .indexAt(viewport().pos()). You may need to fix position a little bit. i.e. move it by headers size. When you have index you can simply call .row() method